# Mongoose function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For some reason my function keeps returning undefined

```
function checkIfExists(pid) {

    const response = Product.exists({pid: pid}, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result) // logs a boolean, the correct result that i want
        return result
    })

    return response
}

console.log(checkIfExists(123)) // returns undefined
```

Why does it return undefined?

Comment: try using async await/ promises. your console statement getting executed before you have response from checkIfExists().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the **exists** function in **mongoose** is like **collection.exists($query, callback)** and returns nothing, that is why you have undefined.

I advise you to use **Promise** to get something when you call your function

```
function checkIfExists(pid) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   Product.exists({pid: pid}, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result) // logs a boolean, the correct result that i want
    resolve(result);
   })
});}
```

Then call it like this:

```
checkIfExists(123).then(function(response) { console.log(response); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the parameter "pid" in your function. Maybe there's a conflict with the names.

And you can log the error to clarify ur situation:

```
function checkIfExists(_pid) {
    // where _pid receive the argument
    // and pid is the field name of ur col
    const response = Product.exists({pid: _pid}, function (err, result) {
        if(err) return err
        else    return result;
    })

    return response
}

console.log(checkIfExists(123))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Product.exists()` function will be running `asynchronously` and currently, you are returning the  `response` before function completes the execution. That's why you are getting `undefined`.

One way to solve this is you can pass the callback to the `checkIfExists` function

```js
function checkIfExists(pid, callback) {
  User.exists({ pid: pid }, callback);
}

checkIfExists(pid, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```